# M as set of tuples and its smallest cartesian product

Tags: set-theory

> Given a set $M$ of ordered pairs it is sometimes of interest to
> determine the smallest Cartesian product of which $M$ is a subset. The
> smallest $A$ and $B$ such that $M \subseteq A \times B$ can be found
> by taking $A=\{a \mid\langle a, b\rangle \in M$ for some $b\}$ and
> $B=\{b \mid\langle a, b\rangle \in M$ for some $a\}$. These two sets
> are called the projections of $M$ onto the first and the second
> coordinates, respectively. For example, if $M=\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle   1,2\rangle,\langle 3,2\rangle\}$, the set $\{1,3\}$
> is the projection onto the first coordinate, and $\{1,2\}$ the
> projection onto the second coordinate. Thus $\{1,3\} \times\{1,2\}$ is
> the smallest Cartesian product of which $M$ is a subset.

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what "for some a" and "for some b" mean.
I can't make sense of how to recombine the tuples in order to form the projections. maybe, could someone give me another example where "1"is mapped either to a or b? like substituting with a 4 or whathaveyou ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "For some" means just what it does in normal english. $A$ is the set of all objects that appear on the left of a pair in $M$, while $B$ is the set of all objects that appear on the right of a pair in $M$. $A = \{1,3\}$ because there are pairs in $M$ with $1$ as the left element, and another pair with $3$ as the left element. $2 \notin A$ because there is no pair in $M$ with $2$ as the left element. Similar remarks apply to right elements and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

I can reword the statement without using the phrasing that seems to be confusing you:

**For all points $(x,y) \in M$, $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.**

Once we have found the smallest such $A, B$ which satisfies this condition for all tuples in M, $A \times B$ is the smallest Cartesian product.

To now address your questions:

- **What does "for some a" and "for some b" mean?** It means that if $x \in A$, there must be a corresponding $y \in B$ such that $(x,y) \in M$.  Not all combinations of $(x,y)$ will work, but at least one such combination works.
- **How do I form the projections?** Take all of your tuples in M, remove all of the $x$-values, and use them to build the set A.  Similarly, remove all of the $y$-values, and use them to build the set B.  In the case of the following set $M = \{(1,4), (2, 3), (5, 1), (7, 7), (8,4)\}$, we can see that the $x$-values are $A = \{1, 2, 5, 7, 8\}$ and the $y$-values are $B = \{1, 3, 4, 7\}$. (Notice that B only has four values because the $4$ was repeated.)

Comment: thank you so much! got it